# Prove facts about numbers given inequalities

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Given the three inequalities:

\begin{align}
bc &< -2\\
d &> 2\\
(d-2)^2 &> 4d(-2-bc)
\end{align}

Show that $b$ and $c$ must have opposite signs.

---

I'm not really sure where to start here..

Comment: Note that the product of $b$ and $c$ is going to be a negative number. Now, what could you derive from that? Remember that a negative times a negative is positive and two positive numbers multiplied together will also be positive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get you started:  The first inequality is all you need to use from your problem to show that $b$ and $c$ have opposite signs.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:  Just the first inequality says that $bc$ must be negative.